# truffle - artifacts.require is not a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am currently learning solidity and creating my first project. I am trying to test the deployment of my contract with truffle and i keep getting the below error

```
TypeError: artifacts.reqiure is not a function
```

Syntax looks correct and there are no errors appearing. I have also gone into the truffle console and the migration seems to have deployed ok and Color.json is now in my abis folder as well.

Any help will be appreciated, all files are below.

Color.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "./ERC721Full.sol";

contract Color is ERC721Full {

  // Initialise function 
  constructor () ERC721Full("Color", "COLOR") public {
    
  }

}
```

Color.test.js

```
const Color = artifacts.reqiure('./Color.sol')

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()

contract('Color', (accounts) => {
  let contract
  
  before(async () => {
    contract = await Color.deployed()
  })

  describe('deployment,', async() => {
    it('deploys successfully', async() => {
      contract = await Color.deployed()
      const address = contract.address
      console.log(address)
      assert.notEqual(address,"")
      assert.notEqual(address, 0x0)
      assert.notEqual(address, null)
      assert.notEqual(address, undefined)
    })

    it('has a name', async () => {
      const name = await contract.name()
      assert.equal(name, 'Color')
    })

    it('has a symbol', async () => {
      const symbol = await contract.symbol()
      assert.equal(symbol, 'COLOR')
    })
  })
})
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const Color = artifacts.require("Color");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Color);
};
```

1_init_migration.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in Color.test.js

```
const Color = artifacts.reqiure('./Color.sol')
```

should be `require`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5');
```

Before you're trying to call `artifacts.require`

Comment: should add this line in `hardhat.config.js` file

Comment: that worked for me.
add to the hardhat.config.js file

Answer (score 1):

I tried out this particular code and it shows out an error message and after looking into the line it is just a small spelling error in this particular line in the color code: -

```
const Color = artifacts.reqiure('./Color.sol')
```

Try replacing it with this: -

```
const Color = artifacts.require('./Color.sol')
```